# I am getting Format of date time 2023-07-17T07:00:00.000Z in my LWC component, but i want only date

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

{label:'Start Date',fieldName:'StartDateTime',type:'Date-time'},

datatable in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation of formatted-date-time.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation

To change the date format use typeAttributes

```
{ label: 'Start Date', fieldName: 'StartDateTime', type: 'date',
typeAttributes:{
        year: "numeric",
        month: "numeric",
        day: "numeric"
    } },
```

Thanks!

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. You should reproduce the important parts of the information from the link here (because links have a habit of becoming invalid over time)

Comment: Thanks @DerekF, Updated the answer.